# Vertical Scrolling - Add content below visible area and Design UI - Windows Phone 8.1 XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add a vertical scroll-able content to a page.

I have split the vertical space using 5 grid heights of 300 pixels each and added the scroll viewer and it works fine.

The problem is Visual Studio shows only 2 grid heights in the XAML Visual Editor, and the remaining 3 goes to the bottom and nothing is visible.

However, if designate items to the remaining grids using XAML code, they are in place.

How do I view them in the Visual Editor and design my UI?

Thanks.

Comment: Paste your xaml code in the question . so, that we can fix up your issue with what you have actually done.

Comment: The example code Chubosaurus Software given below is same as my code but I use shares <RowDefinition Height="1*"/> instead of exact pixel values. There is a problem in using the d:DesignHeight. I have replied to Chubosaurus Software.

Comment: The example code Chubosaurus Software given below is same as my code. There is a problem in using the d:DesignHeight. I have replied to Chubosaurus Software. Ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but I will post my workaround below.

In your `<Page>` specify a maximum design height like so:

```XAML
<Page
    x:Class="YOUR_CLASS.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YOUR_CLASS"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="2000">
```

The key thing is : `d:DesignHeight="your_height"`

Then you can force it to draw the "hidden" content, but it looks kinda ugly.

For example:

```XAML
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid Height="2000">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="4" Background="Red">
            <Border Background="Red" Height="200" Width="200" ></Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

will result in

[image]

Comment: If I use  d:DesignHeight="2000" as an example, My grid height * shares the 2000 pixels. In simple, I want to divide the screen height into 3 shares and add scrollable content in the 3 grid. For that (Just for design purpose), I want extent the limit of the xaml visual editor for grid 3 alone.

Comment: @Ganesh.G yeah, I don't know how to do that, I would give each of the grids a static height in design view and the with grid #3 the remaining height.  So lets say 2000 d:Height with a Phone emulator height of 800.. then first grid is 800/3 = 266, second grid is 266, and #3 will be 1468.  I'm not sure you can ever get scroll to work in design view -- that would be kind of award positioning UI elements, imho.